# spring boot CrudRepository query passing object mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have the following code:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {


@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO users(email, password, name) VALUES (?,?,?)", nativeQuery = true)
void insertUserToUsers(String email, String password, String name);
}
```

I don't want to pass the values, i want to pass a user object like this:

```
void insertUserToUsers(User user);
```

Comment: Why are you using this custom method to save a user? CruRepository already have `save()` method. You can save a User with that method.

Comment: Why don't you use `userRepository.save(user)` ?

Comment: Spring JPA will take care of the crud operation. You can just save your entity   UserRepository.save(user)

Comment: @EmreSavcı i had a table named "users". crude made a new table user instead of using users, if i change it from users to user it will work but then that means that the name of the table must be equal to the name of the object

Comment: You can put `@Table(name = "users")` annotation on your entity. It will map to your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {


@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO users(email, password, name) VALUES (:#{#user.email},:#{#user.firstname},:#{#user.name})", nativeQuery = true)
void insertUserToUsers(@Param("user") User user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
    @Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO users(email, password, name) VALUES (?,?,?)", nativeQuery = true)
void insertUserToUsers(String email, String password, String name);

default void insertUserToUsers(User user) {
    return insertUserToUsers(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you use your `UserRepository` you can use the default method to save `user`:

ex:

```
@Service
public class MyService{

 @Autowired
 private UserRepository userRepository ;

 public void example(User user){

  userRepository.save(user)

 }
}
```

Because CrudRepository give us some default methods , you can check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)